# What's the generalizable way to get values out of a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a little threaded discussion board in angular. I want to use hallo.js for my inline editor (or something similar, the problem doesn't actually depend on hallo).

Here's the relevant snippet from the template

```
<div ng-show="post.editing" ng-bind-html="post.body" edit-hallo class="col-xs-8"></div>
<div ng-show="!post.editing" ng-bind-html="post.body" class="col-xs-8"></div>
```

Here's my directive:

```
Appl.directive('editHallo', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      element
        .hallo({
          plugins: {
            'halloformat': {"bold": true, "italic": true, "strikethrough": true, "underline": true},
            'halloheadings': [1,2,3],
            'hallojustify' : {},
          }
        });

      element.bind('hallomodified', function(event, data) {
        scope.post.body = data.content;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This all works just fine, but the hack is right there at the end - when there's a hallomodified event, I manually say, `scope.post.body = data.content` which not only feels like a hack, it means this only works when there's a post.body item that I'm editing, and therefore doesn't work well if I want to repurpose this for the profile editor or whatever.

So my question is: how should I refactor this so that the relevant two-way binding works? I tried a few things that seemed obvious, such as putting a `app-model="post.body"` in the div, and then doing an isolate scope with =, but that wasn't getting me anywhere. Ideally, I'd pass in the appropriate model using an ng-model directive, but that seems to have changed sometime between when all the directive examples I found online were created and angular 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

There's been some time I don't use AngularJS.

But I think the best way would be to change the scope to something like:

```
scope:{ngModel:'='}
```

or

```
scope:{attribute:'='}
```

That way it should make a two data binding. One with ng-model on first case, or attribute on second.

Then you can just do this when event happens:

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.ngModel=newValue;
})
```

The apply will be needed so angular can call digest cycle again and update the view.

More info, I think this can help:
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: I would avoid calling your attribute `ngModel`, otherwise it's easy to mix it up with the `ngModel` directive - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel. This directive takes a bit more work to use properly that a basic two way binding, but looks after things like registering itself in forms and validating input.

Comment: The comments in the doc page you linked there, @Andyrooger ended up pointing me in the right direction. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms about halfway down the page - custom form controls with ngModel. I'm still not sure precisely why it works, but basically copying that example code does what I need. I set the text field as an ng-model on the directive tag, and it's accessible through the controller injected to the link function.

Comment: Good to hear. I think `ngModel` is simple and powerful but hard to find the right information for normally. If you don't need the form functionality then the binding described above (with a non-ng-model attribute) is much more straight forward, otherwise `ngModel` is brilliant.

Comment: Yes... I did not write any angular code for a while, but I remmeber that make the validation work right was difficult too. Never understood this part exactly.